# sending keystrokes to external application

Tags: c#, simulation, keystroke

I made some software using the kinect to classify gestures and want to use those gestures to play a mario game on a emulator running on the pc.

To play it, I try to send keystrokes to the emulator.
In my code I first bring up the window (this works):

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("nnnesterJ")[0];
SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
```

And then I try to send keystrokes:

```
         case Movement.left: SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}"); break;
        case Movement.right: SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}"); break;
        case Movement.upperleft: SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}{UP}"); current_move = Movement.stop; break;
        case Movement.upperright: SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}{UP}"); current_move = Movement.stop; break;
        case Movement.jump: SendKeys.SendWait("{UP}"); current_move = Movement.stop; break;
        case Movement.crouch: SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}"); break;
```

However, this is not working :( I did try this in excel and then it does work (and yes I'm sure the keys are actually correct).

I also tried doing this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
        public static void PressKey(Keys key, bool up)
        {
            const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
            const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
            if (up)
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
            }
            else
            {
                keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
            }
        }
```

but unfortunately this also doesn't work. Does anybody have some options?

Kind regards,
Héctor

Comment: Can you check if On-Screen Keyboard is working with emulator? It may give us additional info.

Comment: The on-screen keyboard (e.g. in google) is working and in other applications (like excel) sending key commands it is also working

Answer (score 0):

It seems your emulator runs elevated while your app doesn't.

Try run as administrator with your application, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SendInput API?

Using this class: https://github.com/Ben-Barron/PS3BluMote/blob/master/SendInputAPI.cs

To use:

```
var keyboard = new SendInputAPI.Keyboard();

// ...

keyboard.sendKey(SendInputAPI.Keyboard.KeyCode.A);
```

Or:

```
var keys = new List<KeyCode> { KeyCode.Ctrl, KeyCode.C }; // order does matter.

keyboard.sendKeysDown(keys);
keyboard.releaseLastKeys();
```

Answer (score -1):

why dont you try SetActiveWindow(hwnd) from USER32 after SetForegroundWindow(hwnd).. I think that will solve your problem